# using auth header to prevent access to page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

On login action I'm storing inside localstorage `username` and `token` for logged user where afterwards I'm creating auth. headers that post request.

Update:
to be more specific on this. I have `userService` which succ. put and retrieve users data from the localstorage, where I have `username`, `sessionId`, and `isLogged`.

My question is: Now having Auth. header, all info I need about logged user inside localstorage, how can I write an event handler to check if the user is logged in before each route change.

Should I do that on app.js where I init my app and to inject userService? if yes how.

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    var app = angular.module("myApp",
        ["common.services",
            "ui.router",
            "ui.mask",
            "userService", 
            "ui.bootstrap"]);
    ....
```

[image]

> How can I now use this stored auth header in order to access/deny
>   access to specific pages?

**Update 2: app.js**

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    var app = angular.module("myApp",
        ["common.services",
            "ui.router",
            "ui.mask",
            "userService",
            "ui.bootstrap"]);        

    app.config(["$stateProvider", "$urlRouterProvider",
            function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
                $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

                $stateProvider
                    .state("index", {
                        url: "/",
                        templateUrl: "app/index.html",
                    })
                    // Restricted
                    .state("home", {
                        url: "/home",
                        templateUrl: "app/home/home.html",
                        controller: "HomeController as vm"
                    })
            }]
    );
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by marking required routes with custom attribute and  verifying that token is valid when "location" is changing.

**Update** Assuming you can verify that user is authenticated by checking `isLogged` property of `userService`:

```
(function () {
"use strict";
var app = angular.module("myApp",
    ["common.services",
        "ui.router",
        "ui.mask",
        "userService",
        "ui.bootstrap"]);

app.config(["$stateProvider", "$urlRouterProvider",
    function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

        $stateProvider
            .state("index", {
                url: "/",
                templateUrl: "app/index.html",
            })
            // Restricted
            .state("home", {
                url: "/home",
                templateUrl: "app/home/home.html",
                controller: "HomeController as vm",
                data: {
                    requiresLogin: true
                }
            })
    }]
).run(['$rootScope', '$state', 'userService', function($rootScope, $state, userService) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(e, to) {
        if (to.data && to.data.requiresLogin && !userService.isLogged) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $state.go('index');
        }
    })
}]);
}());
```

Comment: great, i just updated question with my whole app.js code. Please can you post your code into app.js as an extended answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i think that the right approach to your problem is to use resolve property in the route, so the user can't navigate to certain pages if he isn't logged in and once he logged in you can inject the user object to the controller

for example to navigate to home page you must be logged in

```
.when("/home", {
templateUrl: "homeView.html",
controller: "homeController",
resolve: {
    user: function(AuthenticationService){
      return AuthenticationService.getUser();
    }
  }
})

app.controller("homeController", function ($scope, user) {
   $scope.user = user;
});
```

good example: https://www.sitepoint.com/implementing-authentication-angular-applications/